# ERROR!!! Wrong Android API version: 4.2, Issue with running android 4.2 with rhodes

Tags: android, rhomobile, rhodes

I was facing the same error "ERROR!!! API version is not found in installed Android SDK: 1.6". But on adding this block, within the build.yml of my rhodes app:

android:
  version: 4.2
  emulator: rhoAndroid
Now I am getting this error:ERROR!!! Wrong Android API version: 4

rake run:android --trace 
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.0.5/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.2.2 
** Invoke run:android (first_time) 
** Invoke run:android:emulator (first_time) 
** Invoke device:android:debug (first_time) 
** Invoke package:android (first_time) 
** Invoke build:android:all (first_time) 
** Invoke build:android:rhobundle (first_time) 
** Invoke config:android (first_time) 
** Invoke config:set_android_platform (first_time) 
** Execute config:set_android_platform 
** Execute config:android 
** Invoke config:common (first_time) 
** Execute config:common 
Use Google addon API: false 
+++ Looking for platform... 
+++ API LEVEL of D:/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/platforms/android-16: 16 
+++ API LEVEL of D:/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/platforms/android-4.2: 17 
Found API levels: 
16 
17 
Requested version: 4.2 
Corresponding API level 
ERROR!!! Wrong Android API version: 4.2

In build.yml 
android: 
version: 4.2

In rhobuild.yml, all the necessary setting for android , ndk, jdk are there 
env: 
app: D:/ColumnMobility_ITSM 
paths: 
android-ndk: D:/Android/android-ndk-r8b-windows/android-ndk-r8b 
java: C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0/bin 
android: D:/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/adt-bundle-windows/sdk

**I am using rhodes 3.2.2, with android 4.2sdk**
Where can I found, which are the android os supported by rhodes?

Any help will be highly appreciable

Comment: Try with this link
 https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rhomobile/EfR-Ui5LY1I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhodes 3.3.1 onwards supports Android SDK 4.0 and NDK r7.
Use Rhodes 3.3.2 which also fixes the database encryption issue on Android 4.0
https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/master/CHANGELOG